# Unicode support in MFC, Visual C++ file operations

Tags: file, visual-c++, unicode, mfc

I wanted to add `<br/>` tag for each and every line of a file. So I have written the following line of code.

It is working fine for English files.

```
CFileDialog cfd(TRUE);
CString filename, strLine;

if(cfd.DoModal()== IDOK)
{
    filename = cfd.GetPathName();
    CStdioFile infile(filename, CFile::modeRead); 
    CStdioFile fileout(filename+L"out.txt", CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite);
    while(infile.ReadString(strLine)) 
    {
        fileout.WriteString(strLine);
        fileout.WriteString(L"<br/>\n");                    
    }
    infile.Close();
    fileout.Close();
}
```

But the same program reads and writes only first string in the output file for Tamil (UNICODE). Is there any solution to resolve this issue?

How to do it ? Simple codes are welcome. I don't want to use FILE pointers and fstream.. :)

Comment: When you say "Unicode", which of the many possible Unicode encodings do you mean? Is the file encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16LE, something else? In the first two cases, you might be able to make it work by calling `_setmode(fileno(infile.m_pStream), _O_U8TEXT);` (for UTF-8; use `_O_U16TEXT` for UTF-16LE), and similarly for `fileout`, right after opening each.

Comment: go here: http://utf8everywhere.org, skip to "windows"